# How to use $ character in sass file

Tags: css, sass, less

I have some sass files that contain the $ character.
All files get errors when compiling. Because $ is reserved in sass.
In the next example I want to select all css classes ending with 9.
How to use $ Any idea .

```
[class$="9"]:after {
    background-color: #3d9970 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what compiler you are using (`dart` or `node`) but you should be able to escape it using `#{'$'}`:

```
[class#{'$'}="9"]:after {
    background-color: #3d9970 !important;
}
```